# discord.py: Как сделать команду которая банит пользователя написавшего её

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Надо что бы была команда которая делает БАН на пользователя написавшего её

Comment: Добавить команду боту, в методе, вызываемом при выполнении команды, сделать бан юзера, вызывавшего его. Если у вас проблемы с кодом, то добавьте его и опишите в чем ошибка :)

Comment: Я не знаю аргумента который делает это на пользователя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.author.ban()
```